# Send an email to a custom object's email field along with its related list

Tags: email

I have a custom object called Attendee, it has email field and related list for the registered Event (also a custom object). I would like to send an email to the Attendee's email with his/her related list information. Thanks.

Comment: Please modify your question and input what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Create a visualforce template, and message the child records to include them within the email.

Link: [VisualForce Email Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample)

Comment: Thanks, I have the Attendee custom object (which is a "person") that I want to use as the recipientType. I want to send an email every time a attendee signs up an event, so in the email body it will need to have related list from the attendee as well. Thanks. I've tried HTML email but it doesn't allow to have related list. I've tried to use visualforce but it doesn't allow to have custom object as the receipientType.